# How to extract array fields from json field (mongodb) with 'textractjsonfield' and why rows are passed but not showed in the 'tlog'

Tags: talend

I have a collection named 'collaborators' in nosql database (mongodb), [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43Qsu.png)
I want to extract the first row of the array 'contracts' with 'textractjsonfield',
rows are passed but not showed, why ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXi8N.png)
This is the component config,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4Pse.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFREQ.png)

JSONpath
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D30Ns.png)

i want some informations about the component config

.............................................

this is the 'contracts' field data with 'tlogrow'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M9tk.png)
this is the output of the job with 'textractjsonfield'
[enter image description here][3]
and this is the configuration of 'textractjsonfield' component
[enter image description here][4]

---

while creating "$oid" ddddd
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D30Ns.png)

---

this is the table config and the tlogrow output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D30Ns.png)

Comment: if you add a tLogRow between the mongo component and the tExtractJSONFields, is there data printed ?

Comment: yes it load data effectively but nothing showed with textractjsonfield,

Comment: even i followed a tuto on yt but the same problem appear

Comment: Also I just saw in your tExtractJSONFields you put "$.*" in the JSON path put "$.[*]" and could you also edit your post and add the output of the first tlogRow (that print the mongo data)

Comment: post edited, thank you

Comment: i modified the contract field type "object"

Comment: also i added the jsonpath in the post

Comment: also in the tExtractJSONFields in the JSON Request instead of "oid" set it to "$oid"

Comment: it read only "$.oid", exectution error appear while creating "$oid",
check the post edit

Comment: yeah I forgot that the $ is an issue in the json path so do the same with but replace it with : "['$oid']" I think you don't have anything in output because the field is '$oid' and you try to get 'oid'

Comment: JSON field : contacts
JSONPath loop query : "$.[*]"
Mapping : oid         "['$oid']"
=> The same problem, bothing shown in the output

Comment: Is there a solution with xpath  ?

Comment: can you set the tLogRow (between mongo input and tExtractJSONFields) parameter 'mode' to table and show the schema in output of mongo and also show the mongo component configuration

Comment: Yeah sure, check the post

Comment: Oh ok, my bad when I tried to replicate your issue I used a different structure for the array. So can you try changing jsonpath to xpath and for the loop set it to "/" and for the xpath request "." and leave the rest unchecked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for the issue, the problem was the path to the array.

The easiest solution is to change the JSONPath option to Xpath and set the loop to "/" and the Xpath request to "." :

[image]

So if you have data like this [test1,test2,test3] , you can have an issue processing it so first I processed it in a tMap to make it usable by a tExtractJSONFields

[image]

(the content.toString() is because of the way I read the sample data, it's unecessary for the base problem) and the

```
.replaceAll("\\[", "\\[\"").replaceAll("\\]", "\"\\]").replaceAll(",", "\",\"")
```

Is to make the string / array usable by the tExtractJSONFields.

And then with the configuration of the tExtractJSONFields, you have this output

[image]

Comment: It works now, thanks lot I appreciate.

Comment: Nice, glad I could help :)